# Is it an obligation to be a Brahmin to study advaita vedanta?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, upanishads, brahma-sutras

Is it an obligation to be a Brahmin to study advaita vedanta ?

Comment: Well depends on what you mean by study exactly.

Answer (score 2):

> For the Brāhmaṇas he ordained teaching, **studying**, sacrificing and officiating at sacrifices, as also the giving and accepting of gifts. ([Manu Smriti 1.88](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145532.html)).

Also,

> Teaching and **studying**, offering sacrifices and officiating at sacrifices, and giving and accepting gifts are the six occupations of a highest-born person. - [Manu Smriti 10.75](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201811.html)

Now, the question is what we mean by studying. Commentator of Manusmriti - Medhatithi did not throw any light on it. However, this has been made explicit in other Smritis.

> The duties of the Brāhmaṇa are six: **studying the Veda**, teaching, sacrificing, officiating as a priest for others, giving alms and accepting gifts. - Vaśiṣṭha 2.13-14

> Every twice-born one is entitled to prosecute the **study of the Vedas**, to celebrate Vedic sacrifices and to practice charities. Of these, teaching, the celebration of religious sacrifices (for others), and acceptance of gifts are functions which specifically from the right of a Brahmana. - Gautama 10.1-3

Thus, you see that studying Vedas is an obligation, but studying specifically Advaita Vedanta is not an obligation. Just to clarify, Advaita Vedanta interprets Vedic texts in a specific way. But there are other interpretations as well (For example, Dvaita Vedanta etc.) Which interpretation you would read depends on your likings.